# PrintWindow: screenshot is offset sometimes

Tags: winapi, screenshot

I'm taking screenshots of windows using PrintWindow(). This works finde with the following code.

This works most of the time - I'm calling it very often in a continuos loop - but sometimes it fails. I started saving screenshots of the times it fails. Sometimes they are just black, but sometimes the ClientArea of the captured window is somehow offset and only visible on half the picture. Why is that the case?

EDIT:
Is the PrintWindow function guaranteed to work, even when its called ~100times a second? What makes me wonder is, that after every print window I'm actually verifying two pixels which default colors I stored as a COLORREF at startup. The program says they match almost all the time. Still, once I use GetPixel, the returned value from other pixels is simply black or white from time to time (which should never be the case). Once I save the HDC/HBITMAP as a screenshot (I called GdiFlush before), the screenshot is just plain black (which shouldn't be the case either, as I said, I checked two pixels before...). 
Well for now, back to the initial question: Is this definitely my fault, or is it possible that PrintWindow just gives random results from time to time, without returning an error?

Ok, this is the NEW CODE:

```
    /* Try printing the window 10times, in case it fails. */
for (int i = 0; i <= NUM_ITERATIONS_PREP; i++) {
    releaseSurface();
    prepared_HWND = hwnd;
    window_dc = GetWindowDC(hwnd);
    surface = CreateCompatibleDC(window_dc);
    if (surface) {
        RECT r;
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, &r);
        bmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(window_dc, r.right - r.left, r.bottom - r.top);
        if (!ReleaseDC(hwnd, window_dc)) {
            writeLog("ReleaseDC failed.", black, true);
        }
        if (bmp) {
            old_surface_bmp = SelectBitmap(surface, bmp);
            //InvalidateRect(hwnd, 0, TRUE);
            //UpdateWindow(hwnd);
            int result = PrintWindow(hwnd, surface, 0);
            if (result != 0) {
                if (!verify || verifySurface())
                    break;
                else {
                    writeLog("Surface could not be verified on iteration " + std::to_string(i) + ". Saving screenshot.", black, true);
                    saveDebugScreenshot();
                    QThread::msleep(2);
                }
            } else {
                writeLog("PrintWindow() failed.", black, true);
            }
        }
        else {
            writeLog("BMP creation failed.", black, true);
        }
    }
    else {
        writeLog("HDC creation failed.", black, true);
    }
}
```

And the new RELEASE CODE:

```
/* If you call prepareSurface(), call this once the surface isn't need anymore. */
void ClientProfile::releaseSurface() {
    SelectObject(surface, old_surface_bmp);
    DeleteDC(surface);
    DeleteObject(bmp);
    prepared_HWND = NULL;
}
```

releaseSurface() is called either at the beginning of prepareSurface() and additionally every time I'm done processing a table (this means its called once too often for every prepareSurface(). Is that a problem?).

Oh and old_surface_bmp, bmp and surface are declared as private class attributes.

Comment: When you say "it fails" do you mean one of the function calls fails, or just that the captured bitmap is incorrect?

Comment: Just that the bitmap is incorrect. The function calls dont fail, as long as I release the HDC correctly.

Comment: Some GDI calls can be asynchronous, so I guess it's conceivable that when you save your bitmap it's in an inconsistent state. Try calling `GdiFlush` and make sure you deselect your bitmap from the DC before saving it to disk.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. By failing, I mean the PixelColors I receive by GetPixel are simply wrong (they match the saved bmp, but not the clientarea of the window on screen).

Comment: I feel like the window is not fully redrawn before its printed to the HDC, which doesn't really make sense though, because as far as I understand, PrintWindow() erases the background anyway, before repainting it? I implemented check now, which always compares two pixels on the printed image to prestored verification colors, and if they don't match, PrintWindow() is called again. Usually, this has to be repeated 4times until the surface can finally be verified. That seems to work fine so far, even though its more like a workaround.

Comment: Ok, this seems to happen more and more after a certain amount of time. There are no failed prints for a few minutes, and suddenly every print seems to fail and I get alot of false positive pixel checks.

Comment: Sounds like a GDI resource leak.

Comment: In the above code, `SelectObject(surface, bmp);` will leak the original bitmap from `surface`.

Comment: Ok, could you show me the correct way to do this please? I feel like I tried almost everything now and I simply cant figure out how to correctly Select/Release/Delete and whatever...

Comment: Wherever you have `surface` defined, also define `HBITMAP old_surface_bmp`. Then `old_surface_bitmap = SelectObject(surface, bmp);`. Then before you call `DeleteDC(surface);` add `SelectObject(surface, old_surface_bitmap);`.

Comment: Ok, I tried it like that now, and at least it ran stable for 11minutes now. I hope it stays like it. I was using Deleaker before though, and it did not tell me about any GDI leaks. I also switched to not using the PW_CLIENTONLY flag now, because I read somewhere, that it is bugged. I'll let you know, if it turns out to still not work. Thanks so far!!!

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like I'm still getting the problem, it occurs more rarely now though...Ok not even more rarely...sigh...

Comment: Check the rest of your code for similar leaks.

Comment: I really did. I edited my post above with more details and a question.

Comment: Could it be the case, that something with the clipping regions gets mixed up over time?

Comment: Ok, I got it working now by double-checking everything. I still get bad screenshots, I just try to ignore them. I started checking the error codes though, and when I'm screenshotting windows really often (like ~900times/second), I get LastError87 alot ('ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER'). Any ideas why? Thanks.

Comment: When I used PrintWindow(hwnd, surface, 1); instead of PrintWindow(hwnd, surface, 0); it fixed the offset, does this work for you as well?